# Отключить ввод текста в поле TextBox .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Имеется форма `winform` `topmost`, на ней имеется многострочное текстовое поле.
В него выводится лог строки. В поле `TextBox` имеется прокрутка как вертикальная так и горизонтальная. Все хорошо кроме того что в поле свободно можно впечатать текст и там виден курсор ввода. Выставив `enabled = false` поведение меняется и ввести текст нельзя но и прокрутить тоже нельзя, равно как и скопировать часть текста.

Есть ли такая возможность, отключить ввод с клавиатуры для этого элемента?

Comment: Свойство `ReadOnly = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установите свойство IsReadonly=true

Comment: .... как то глупо не заметить это свойство ) спасибо.

Comment: `ReadOnly` правильно называется свойство, исправьте ответ.